# Reducing the size of a Unity3D project

Tags: c#, android, serialization, unity-game-engine, fbx

I am working at a Unity game. The game is made up from more levels(300 or so), and in each level I have a 3D maze (an fbx file imported from 3DS Max). Now I was thinking that the apk file (yes, the project i'm working at is intended for android) will be too big since I have a lot of fbx files(300 or so). So I am looking for a solution to avoid this problem.
   My solution would be to somehow serialize these fbx files and load them at runtime, each for its own level, but I don't know how helpfull this would be. If this could be a solution to my problem, can you please point me to some resources where I can figure it out how to serialize a 3dmodel/prefab/fbx file? And if this wouldn't be of any help for me, can you please tell me what my solutions are?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [Asset Bundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) are a way to go

Comment: even the biggest mesh takes up no room at all - nothing.  Your app icon will be bigger in kilobytes.  the only problem is textures.  As Kay said you may wish to learn about AssetBundles, but I doubt it will be necessary.

Comment: So should I just use something like List<GameObjects> myList? Is that all right?

Comment: I agree with Joe. Assuming you share your textures between levels, the fbx files alone won't be an issue for your final app size. Have a preconfigured prefab in your Resources folder for every level, making sure they share Materials while all having their own Mesh (fbx). From there you can conveniently load them by name at runtime.

Comment: All of my meshes use the same material(nothing too fancy). So i'll store those mazes as prefabs and store them into a List<GameObject>. Thank you for your help guys!